# python garbage collector behavior on compound objects

Tags: python, garbage-collection, python-internals

Does python garbage collector cleans up a compound object if some of its parts are still referenced

e.g.

```
def foo():
    A = [ [1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
    return A[1]
B = foo()
```

Will `A[0]` be garbage collected?

Is there a way to confirm the same through code?

Comment: You could confirm it by making A[0] a simple object with a __del__ method that prints a message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nothing references the list `A` and the nested list `A[0]`, so yes, they will be deleted from memory.

The nested list object referenced by `A[1]` has no connection back to its original container.

Note that it's not the garbage collector that does this; the GC only deals in breaking circular references. This simple case is handled entirely by reference counting.

The moment `foo()` returns, the local namespace is cleared up. That means `A` is removed, which means the list object reference count drops to 0. This clears that list object, which means that the *contained* lists also see their reference count drop by one. For `A[0]` that means the count drops to 0 too and it is cleared.

For the list object referenced by `A[1]`, you now have a reference `B` to it, so it's count is  still 1 and it remains 'alive'.

To confirm the same through code, simply use a subclass of `list` with a [`__del__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) to let us know when the object is being deleted:

```
>>> class DelList(list):
...     def __del__(self):
...         print 'Deleted {}'.format(self)
... 
>>> def foo():
...     A = DelList([DelList([1, 3, 5, 7]), DelList([2, 4, 6, 8])])
...     return A[1]
... 
>>> B = foo()
Deleted [[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
Deleted [1, 3, 5, 7]
>>> del B
Deleted [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

All this is specific to CPython (the reference Python implementation); other implementations may handle object lifetimes differently (e.g. do use a garbage collector to destroy objects in sweeps), but the lifetime of `A` and `A[0]` doesn't change in those cases; the GC will still collect those in other implementations, albeit at a different point in time perhaps.

Comment: Of course, all of this is CPython-specific. Also, inserting an `__del__` can stop the "real" garbage collector from collecting the object.

Comment: @larsmans: yes, a set of objects involved in a reference cycle where one of them has a `__del__` method will stop the GC from breaking that cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Martijn has explained that `A[0]` will be collected, and here is how to observe it with code:

```
class Bye(object):
   def __del__(self):
      """A special method, called when the object is destroyed."""
      print 'bye'

def foo():
    A = [Bye(), [1,2]]
    return A[1]

foo()
```

Prints:

```
bye
[1, 2]
```